# Selenium run same test on different platforms in parallel

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I have three classes with different tests that I want to execute on chrome browser. The most important thing is that I want to run in parallel on Windows and macOS. How should I do it on Selenium 4 with Hub - > node setup?

My testng file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite 1" parallel="classes" verbose="1" >

    <test name="Test windows and macOS">
        <classes>
            <class name="test1"/>
            <class name="test2"/>
            <class name="test3"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

When test is executed tests are running only on Windows with two browser windows.
Selenium documentation doesn't explain how to do this.

Comment: how many nodes do you have?

Comment: I have three nodes, one is macOS and other two is windows. My goal is to run test in parallel on three this nodes on same browser which in this case will be Chrome.

Comment: can you share your remotewebdriver initialization code?